# Error when trying to style section/subsection

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I've followed this example for section styling.

[How to create custom section titles with a “<title> <number>” format in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193446/how-to-create-custom-section-titles-with-a-title-number-format-in-latex)

There's no error in the MWE, but as soon as I insert it in my thesis, it gives me this error at each occurrence of a section or subsection. I have all required libraries.

I've adapted the code as follows.

[image]

```
        %Title 
    \titleformat{\section}[hang]{\sffamily\color{DarkGrey}\bfseries\scshape\fillright\lsstyle}{}{0.5em}{{\Huge\thesection}\quad\rule[-0.25cm]{1.5pt}{1cm}\quad\Huge#1}%
    
    % Subtitle
    \titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\sffamily\color{DarkGrey}\bfseries\scshape\fillright\lsstyle}{}{0.5em}{{\Large\thesubsection}\hspace{0.15cm}\rule[-0.15cm]{1.5pt}{0.7cm}\hspace{0.15cm}\Large#1}%
    
    Original line of code from exemple 
    \titleformat{\section}[hang]{\sffamily\color{IndianRed3}\bfseries\scshape\filleft\lsstyle}{}{2em}{#1\quad\rule[-0.25cm]{1.5pt}{1cm}\rlap{\qquad\Huge \thesection}}%
```

MWE in wich problem occurs

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic,lipsum,etoolbox}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{letterspace}
\definecolor{DarkGrey}{RGB}{60, 60, 60}

%First title
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193446/how-to-create-custom-section-titles-with-a-title-number-format-in-latex
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\sffamily\color{DarkGrey}\bfseries\scshape\fillright\lsstyle}{}{0.5em}{{\huge\thesection}\quad\rule[-0.25cm]{1.5pt}{1cm}\quad\Huge#1}%

% Subtitle
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\sffamily\color{DarkGrey}\bfseries\scshape\fillright\lsstyle}{}{0.5em}{{\Large\thesubsection}\hspace{0.15cm}\rule[-0.15cm]{1.5pt}{0.7cm}\hspace{0.15cm}\Large#1}%

    
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction} \label{intr}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Here the raw log for the MWE Error

```
    <argument> ...kGrey}\bfseries \scshape \fillright 
                                                  \lsstyle 
l.22 \section{Introduction}
                            \label{intr}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+lmr on input line 22.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmr.fd
File: ot1lmr.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OML+lmm on input line 22.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omllmm.fd
File: omllmm.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OMS+lmsy on input line 22.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omslmsy.fd
File: omslmsy.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OMX+lmex on input line 22.
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omxlmex.fd
File: omxlmex.fd 2015/05/01 v1.6.1 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 22.
[1
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. Show *your* MWE, so that we can be sure what you actually did. Also, avoid posting screenshots of error messages. Typeset the error using the tools provided by this site. Thank you.

Comment: Did you fail to load either the `microtype` or the `letterspace` package?

Comment: @Miyase I added a MWE, thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Also added the MWE error log

Comment: As the error message says, the problem is `\fillright`. I cannot find any package that provides it, so it might be a custom macro written by someone. If you just remove its two occurrences, the document compiles fine. It's up to you to say whether you like the result or not.

Comment: Yep, you are right. `\fillright` doen't exist. According to titlesec documentation, the command if `\filright` `\filleft`. Thank you

Comment: the titlesec documentation only mentions `\filright` not `\fillright`