# ConTeXt: Is it possible to create a new structure level?

Tags: context

This question is probably stupid but it is okay, let's ask it anyway.

I was wondering if it is possible (and simple), in ConTeXt, to create a whole new structure level "above" `part` (a sort of  `super` structure) with its own settings. I know it is possible, at least in LaTeX (or anything else, but most likely LaTeX), since I have already seen books with a (probably named) `book` structure with its own `part`s, `chapter`s, ..., and even table of contents.

Let's just give an example, it should looks like:

```
MySuperStructure I
    Table of Contents
    Part I
        Chapter 1
        Chapter 2
        ...
    Part II
        Chapter 3
        Chapter 4
    ...
MySuperStructure II
    Table of Contents
    Part I
        Chapter 1
        Chapter 2
        ...
    Part II
        Chapter 3
        Chapter 4

etc...
```

I am aware about [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59595/213111) but it is not really what I want to do. For what I know at this point, I may have to to deal with [strc-def.mkiv](https://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/mkiv/strc-def.mkiv) however it is way to complicated for my level. How to accomplish that in an easy way (well, if that is possible) in ConTeXt?

Comment: How is your "super-structure" different from simply "pushing all levels one step down". For example, part -> My superstructure, chapter -> part, section -> chapter, etc?

Comment: Well, I did not know it was possible. Is there an easy way to do it?